# .htaccess: allow iframe from subdir to be view only from root dir

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a web site and i have an a sub folder there where there is files which i like to be embedded on my index page. But i want to privent users to view that sub folder directly.

So. i have http://mysite.com/index.php where there is an iframe:

and i have a subfolder opt2 with index.php with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/opt2/" id="shopIframe" name="shopIframe" onload="alert('a');" frameborder="0" height="90%" width="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

i have an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://mysite.com/opt2/ [NC]
RewriteRule /*$ http://mysite.com/index.php [R=302,L]
```

is that possible with .htacces?

Comment: You will probably have better luck at serverfault or webmasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referrer would be `http://mysite.com/index.php`, not `http://mysite.com/opt2/`.

Also some firewall software, proxies etc. remove the referrer header, so you'd better first check if referer is available at all.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^opt2/ http://mysite.com/index.php [R=302,L]
```

**addition**

```
<script>
if( self == top )
  location.href='/index.php';
</script>
```

Comment: it works but with a strange behaviour.

if i open mysite.com/opt2/ - it shows the content (but it shouldn't) but if i press F5 i will be redirected to the root dir

Comment: If you want to force it being framed, you could add some JS to do that. See edit above. You can use the referer header for that as you don't know if the referer header is blocked, or not present because the url is loaded directly.